# How to handle multi request with HttpClient and Servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, httpclient

I'm trying to do my thesis, but I make some problem. I don't know how to solve multirequest on servlet. Can you help me? please
Here are my code at httpclient

```
public double similarity(BasicDBObject json, String model) 
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    double value = 0.0;
    try {
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                 "http://localhost:8080/SimilarityServices/compare");
         List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",json.toString() ));

         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",model ));

         httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        String res = null;

        HttpEntity data = response.getEntity();

        if (data != null) {

          InputStream instream = data.getContent();

          byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);

          res = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

          instream.close();

        }

        if(res != null)
        {
            value = Double.parseDouble(res);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error 1");
    }

    return value;

}
```

And here is my code at Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String part1 = request.getParameter("param1"); 
    String part2 = request.getParameter("param2"); 

    BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(part1);
    BasicDBObject model = (BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(part2);

    double re = comparation(obj,model);

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    out.println(re);
    out.close();
}
```

I alse have a function doPost() but inside doPost(), I call doGet().

I have for() as bellow

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
    {
        BasicDBObject cur = (BasicDBObject) list.get(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        result.add(similarity(cur,model[0]));
    }
```

When list.size() < 100, it's good.
But size of my list is 500, sometime the servlet can not receive two parameter (param1 and param2).

Could you help me? please.

Comment: Multirequest as in a queue?

Comment: Is it wrong? ...

Comment: Not wrong. Just clarifying what you want to do.

Comment: I want to receive two param from HttpClient. 
With number of 100 request, it's good.

But with number of 500 request, it crash. Sometime Servlet can not receive two params, param1 and param2 will null.